# Is it possible to vary the time interval while the timer is running in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, simulation

I want to be able to adjust the time interval between the callbacks. I'm using d3's [interval](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#interval) in the following manner:

```js
let timeInterval = 500;
d3.interval(callback, timeInterval);
```

Now, at some point during the execution, I want to be able to adjust the timeInterval's value (via user input) and have it reflect in the speed at which the subsequent callbacks will be executed.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to change an interval's behavior—including its timing—is calling the [`.restart()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/README.md#timer_restart) method on it. Since a [`d3.interval()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/README.md#timer) is just a wrapped [`d3.timer()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/README.md#timer) which is executed periodically it also features said `.restart()` method.

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/README.md#timer_restart) *timer*.**restart**(*callback*[, *delay*[, *time*]]) [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/src/timer.js)
>
> Restart a timer with the specified callback and optional delay and time. This is equivalent to stopping this timer and creating a new timer with the specified arguments, although this timer retains the original invocation priority.

This can be done along the following lines:

```js
const callback = console.log;
const interval = d3.interval(callback, 500);  // initial timing 500ms
interval.restart(callback, 1000);             // updated timing 1000ms
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`d3.interval()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/src/interval.js) apparently returns the timer object that was created.

You can [stop the old timer](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#timer_stop) and start a new one:

```
var intervalTimer;
// ... other code ...
intervalTimer = d3.interval(callback, 500);
// ... other code ...
intervalTimer.stop();
intervalTimer = d3.interval(callback, 100);
// ...
```